# Accessing a device over ICS from the host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, router, ics

(Originally on NetworkEngineering, but I was redirected here.)

I have a laptop connected to a Wi-Fi network, which shares its Wi-Fi network over an Ethernet cable to another router. That router then connects to my Kindle Fire. I have an SSH server running on that Kindle Fire on port 22.

Is there any way I can connect to that Kindle Fire *FROM* the Laptop?

If needed, the laptop is running Debian, so it's not really ICS but rather bridging.

```
Wi-Fi: Linksys
      | Wi-fi
      | ------. 
      v       | Bridged
    Laptop    |
         \----'
          \ Ethernet
           \__.
              |
              v
            Router
              | Wi-Fi
              |
              v
         Kindle Fire
```

Comment: Can you ping the server from your laptop? If you are running a bridge between the two interfaces there is no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: @Scandalist how exactly would I ping the device?

Comment: it is bridging. You should be able to - what's the ip address of the laptop?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek External or Internal?

Comment: hm. ,I think I meant the kindle and the laptop, my bad, and the internal ip address. Your network config is confusing enough a diagram might help ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The Laptops is: 192.168.43.96 and the Kindle fire's is 192.168.1.121 Diagram: ( see edit ).